# How to set the page size dynamically in kendo ui grid in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using kendo ui grid in asp.net mvc application. I have a requriement that i need to bind the value of some integer assigned in the controller (ViewBag) . I have defined the grid like below:

```
<div id="clientsDb">
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.CustomerViewModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.ContactName).Width(140);
        columns.Bound(c => c.ContactTitle).Width(190);
        columns.Bound(c => c.CompanyName);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Country).Width(110);
    })
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 380px;" })
    .Scrollable()
    .Groupable()
    .Sortable()
    .Pageable(pageable => pageable
        .Refresh(true)
        .PageSizes(true)
        .PageSize((int)ViewBag.ItemsPerPage)
        .ButtonCount(5))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("Customers_Read", "Grid"))
    )
)
</div>
```

In the controller i have defined like

```
public ActionResult GridDisplay()
{
   ViewBag.ItemsPerPage = 10;
   return View("gridpage");
}
```

if i am trying like

```
@{
   var ItemsPerPage = ViewBag.ItemsPerPage;
}


var ItemsPerPage = '@(ItemsPerPage)'
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource().query({ page: 1, pageSize: ItemsPerPage });
```

It is working but the datasource is calling twice which reduces performance. 
I want to directly load the grid with the dynamic size.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting pagesize on your grid datasource instead of the grid itself.
I have the following:

```
.DataSource(ds=> ds
  .Ajax()
  .PageSize(50)
  .ServerOperation(false)
  .Read(read => read.Action("xx", "xx", new { ID = @Model.ID })
```

You should be able to replace the .PageSize(50) with your ViewBag value

```
  .PageSize((int)ViewBag.ItemsPerPage)
```